# Como resolver essa parte do problema?

Tags: c, c++, lógica

Estou fazendo um exercício de média em C, consegui fazer quase todo o exercício mas tem uma parte que eu não sei fazer e gostaria de ajuda, botei ela em negrito

Desenvolva um programa quer a partir das três notas mostre a situação do
aluno.  No  caso  do  aluno  em  recuperação  e  prova  final,  **mostre  também
quanto  o  aluno  irá  precisar  para  passar.  No  caso  da  recuperação  a  nota
necessária para passar é dada por 10-Média+2 e na prova final é dada por
10-Média**

Como eu poderia mostrar?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main()

{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "portuguese");
float nota1, nota2, nota3, notas;

printf (" Digite sua primeira nota: ");
scanf ("%f", &nota1);
printf (" Digite sua segunda nota: ");
scanf ("%f", &nota2);
printf (" Digite sua terceira nota: ");
scanf ("%f", &nota3);
notas = (nota1 + nota2 + nota3) / 3.0;
printf (" Sua média é: %.1f \n", notas);


   if (notas < 4.9)
printf (" Você está de recuperação! ");
else if ( notas >= 5 && notas < 6.9) {
printf (" Terá que fazer a prova final \n");
}

if (notas >= 7)
  printf (" Foi aprovado! ");

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A sua logica está errada. Como você fez, se a nota for 4.9 ou 6.9, o aluno não estará em estado nenhum.

```
float notaNecessaria = 0.0;
if (notas < 5){
   printf (" Você está de recuperação! ");
   notaNecessaria = 10 - notas + 2;
   printf("você precisa de %f", notaNecessaria); 
}else if ( notas >= 5 && notas < 7) {
   printf (" Terá que fazer a prova final \n");
   notaNecessaria = 10 - notas;
   printf("você precisa de %f", notaNecessaria); 
}else{
  printf (" Foi aprovado! ");
}
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Olhe como eu fiz, esse código deve funcionar

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main(){

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "PORTUGUESE");
    float nota1, nota2, nota3, media;

    printf ("Digite sua primeira nota: ");
    scanf ("%f", &nota1);
    
    printf ("\nDigite sua segunda nota: ");
    scanf ("%f", &nota2);
    
    printf ("Digite sua terceira nota: ");
    scanf ("%f", &nota3);

    media = (nota1+nota2+nota3)/3;

    printf ("Sua média é: %.1f\n", media);


    if (media <= 4.9)
        printf ("\nVocê está na final! Voce precisa de %.1f pontos para passar!", 10-media);
    else if (media >= 5 && media <= 6.9) {
        printf ("\nTerá que fazer a recuperacao e sua nota necessária para passar é %.1f ", 10-media+2);
    } else printf ("\n Foi aprovado! ");


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```